# html and css trying to get some vertical space around my equations

Tags: html, css, padding, margins

All I am trying to do is get some vertical spacing around equations.  I want to set a certain amount of space that appears before the equation and a certain amount after.  I am trying all sorts of stuff, but it always seems do to something crazy.  I understand about margin collapsing, but it's clearly more than that going on.  I've put in some absurd amounts of space to illustrate the wackiness.  Can anyone help?

calcStyle.css:

```
body {font-size:180%;}
h2 {font-size:250%;}
h1 {font-size:170%;}
table {font-size:150%}
body {margin-left:30px;}
body {margin-right:30px;}
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
blockquote {
    margin-left 55px;
    margin-right 55px;
    font-style: italic;}
h1 {color:#222222;}
td {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

th {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
equation {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    border:50px #eeeeee;
    background-color: #ddddaa
}
```

html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calcStyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    easy math: <br />

    <equation>
        2+2=4
    </equation>
    <br /> 
    hard math:
    <br />
    <equation>
        3+3=6
    </equation>
    <br /><br />
</body>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just a tip -- you can set all 4 margins at once: `margin: Tpx Rpx Bpx Lpx` where T, R, B, L are the top, right, bottom, and left margins. Same for padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your margins off. I have fixed them up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aGTFU/).

In general, you can write your margins like: `margin: top right bottom left` than their allied `margin-*` attributes - where top, right, bottom and left represent the pixel width values that you can give as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a div and setting the class to 'equation' because 'equation' is not a valid html tag. An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/pqpEq/)

```
easy math:

<div class="equation">
    2+2=4
</div>

hard math:
<div class="equation">
    3+3=6
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `equation`. That will solve it. i.e.

in your css:

```
equation {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VGwwL/